# fingerprint device with own characterization system?

Tags: device, fingerprint

I want build a fingerprint control access in Java. I have a device to get a thresholded fingerprint image and I do some image processing, but I get a high rate of error.

My question is, exists a fingerprint sensor device with its own characterization system?. I mean, the device takes a fingerprint and its output is a serial number or an characteristics vector, not a image, I dont want to do a image processing system to do this.

With this data characteristics is very easy to get a degree of similarity between fingerprints and decrease my rate of error, but I dont know if in the market exist that kind of device.

I appreciate a lot if you guys help me to choose what to do, buy a magic fingerprint device or continue with my image processing system.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help file on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match fingerprints, you have to compare minutiae.

Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition

Here some fingerprints scanner with SDK to enroll, capture and check fingerprint:

- http://www.morpho.com/en/biometric-terminals/oem-modules/fingerprint-modules/morphosmart-cbm-series
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

Or you could use [MegaMatch](http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html) SDK, this SDK provides methods to enroll, capture and check on a lot of [fingerprint scanners](http://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?ref=mm).